# Koebe distortion theorem for odd functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S=\{f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ is univalent$\big{|}f(z)=z+a_2z^3+a_3z^3+...\}$;

If $f\in S$ and is an odd function, then we have:

(1)$\frac{|z|}{1+|z|^2}\leq|f(z)|\leq \frac{|z|}{1-|z|^2},$

(2)$\frac{1-|z|^2}{(1+|z|^2)^2}\leq|f'(z)|\leq\frac{1+|z|^2}{(1-|z|^2)^2}$.

My idea:

At first, I tried to make some adjustment on the proof of the normal Koebe distortion theorem, which states for every $f\in S$, we have

(1)$\frac{|z|}{(1+|z|)^2}\leq|f(z)|\leq \frac{|z|}{(1-|z|)^2},$

(2)$\frac{1-|z|}{(1+|z|)^3}\leq|f'(z)|\leq\frac{1+|z|}{(1-|z|)^3}$.

In most references, an important lemma is used to prove the distortion theorem, that is: for $f\in S$ and $\forall z\in \mathbb{D},\; \left|z\frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}-\frac{2|z|^2}{1-|z|^2}\right|\leq \frac{4}{1-|z|^2}$. I tried to improve this estimate by adding the additional condition that $f$ is an odd function, but in vain. The reason is that in the proof of the lemma, the auxiliary function $h(z)=\frac{f\left(\frac{\xi+z}{1+\overline{z}\xi}\right)-f(z)}{(1-|z|^2)f'(z)}$ plays an important role. However, the condition that $f$ is odd can hardly be used.

Then, I tried another way, which succeesfully helped me to prove (1). Actually, every odd function $f$ in the $S$ class can be expressed in this manner: $f(z)=\sqrt{g(z^2)}$, where $g(z)\in S$ and $\sqrt{g(z^2)}$ refers to one analytic branch. Applying this statement, I get $\frac{|z|^2}{(1+|z|^2)}\leq |g(z^2)|\leq\frac{|z|^2}{(1-|z|^2)^2}$, which is exactly what (1) is talking about. However, unfortunately, this idea does not work effrctively when I tried to prove (2).

I do think, with some technical tricks, this problem can be solved successfully.  Any hint or solution is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs to use that $\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|} \le |\frac {zg'}{g}| \le \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$ for all $g \in S$ - this is standard and follows applying the growth theorem to the Mobius transform of $g$ (the $h$ above in the OP as $h_z(-z)=\frac{-g(-z)}{(1-|z|^2)g'(-z)}$ etc).

Then $f^2(z)=g(z^2)$ so $ff'(z)=zg'(z^2)$ or $\frac{zf'}{f}(z)=\frac {z^2g'(z^2)}{g(z^2)}$, so $\frac{1-|z|^2}{1+|z|^2} \le |\frac {zf'}{f}(z)| \le \frac{1+|z|^2}{1-|z|^2}$ and then we apply point 1. and we are done!